# Strapi custom API body response

Tags: typescript, strapi

there is a way to format the custom API response to the format from the content type endpoints that wish to include the data and meta objects for pagination?

Example:

```
data [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
0 Object { id: 1, attributes: {…} }
1 Object { id: 2, attributes: {…} }
2 Object { id: 3, attributes: {…} }
3 Object { id: 4, attributes: {…} }
4 Object { id: 5, attributes: {…} }
5 Object { id: 6, attributes: {…} }
meta Object { pagination: {…} }
pagination Object { page: 1, pageSize: 25, pageCount: 1, … }
```

Preferred to the extent the controller core from strapi factory or calling any object of function in strap not by plugins.

Thanks in advance

Tried with strapi core controller to extend the data and meta object but don't working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: based on this repository https://github.com/oviecodes/foodadvisor_elastic/tree/master/api, i need get proper pagination for the search_restaurant custom API controller. thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

if you are creating a custom api, then you have to handle pagination response by your own, you can query your collection like this

```
strapi.db.query('api::article.article').findMany({
  offset: 15, 
  limit: 10,
});
```

I found a similar post but with graphql, I hope you will get some help how to manage pagination
https://forum.strapi.io/t/strapi-v4-handle-pagination-in-graphql-custom-resolver/24119

Comment: In my case, I don't query any content-type endpoint, so this will not work. thanks

Comment: can you please post your custom api

Comment: this code repository is the one iam based on for my strapi/elasticsearch integration.

https://github.com/oviecodes/foodadvisor_elastic/tree/master/api

Comment: What does your current response look like?

I am assuming when using search it is calling this service.

https://github.com/oviecodes/foodadvisor_elastic/blob/master/api/src/api/search/services/search.js

Which seems that it is just using entiryService which will not return pagination data, and you would have to write your own implementation like @mainak mentioned.